# How to open email compose screen in Gmail Android/iPhone from anchor click in browser

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

I want to open the compose email screen with prefilled 'to' and 'body' fields in Android/iPhone when the user taps on anchor tag in a web page. The current URL I am using opens compose screen in desktop but in the Mobile browser, it opens Gmail inbox in the browser itself.

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=info&#64;demo.com&su=Query&body=Hello
```

Comment: Why dont you use `mailto` with `subject` and `body` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mailto it will open up email app. I have tested this in android

```
mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Your subject&body=Your body
```

Comment: That would be `mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Your+subject&body=Your+body`